# how can i get all the input as a string if it has different types of white spaces characters?

Tags: c++, input, getline

for example,
input:

there are good times
and there are bad times
END

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
//there are good times
//and there are bad times
//END

int main()
{
    string str;
    getline(cin, str);
    cout << str;
}
```

how can i get it in once all the charecters, getline only gets the part of "there are good times"

Comment: You're going to have to write a parser that looks for the ending sequence (in your case, "END").

Comment: Yes, `getline` only _gets_ one _line_, hence the name. You'll have to call it multiple times, stopping when you get `END`.

Comment: Truth be told, `getline` gets up to whatever delimiting character you tell it to use. Unfortunately in this case there needs to be a strong emphasis on *delimiting character*. One character.

Answer (score 0):

Although it might not be a efficient way to do you can check each line you inputed in a while loop and stop when it matches with your end string (`"END"`), like this..

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
//there are good times
//and there are bad times
//END

int main()
{
    string str;
    string currentLine;
    string endLine = "END";
    
    while (getline(cin >> ws, currentLine))
    {
        if (currentLine == endLine)
            break;
        
        str += currentLine + "\n";
    }
    
    cout << str;
    return 0;
}
```

If you want it to be more concise you can put the line checking inside the while loop

```
while (getline(cin >> ws, currentLine) && currentLine != endLine)
    str += currentLine + "\n";
```

Comment: use the std::getline() function to get the entire line of input,
To ensure that you get all types of white spaces characters, you can use the std::ws manipulator. This manipulator discards any leading whitespace characters before reading the input.

Here's an example code snippet that demonstrates this:              
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main() {
    std::string input;
    std::getline(std::cin >> std::ws, input);  // read entire line, including all whitespace characters
    std::cout << "Input: " << input << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

Comment: I updated the code with `std::ws` , thanks